# Distinguishing Kinesis Firehose Sources in AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have data from AWS DynamoDB being streamed from Kinesis to S3 through Kinesis Firehose.  I need the data to be transformed and partitioned in two different but related ways, so I'm considering creating a second firehose for the other type of transformation.  I would like to use a single Lambda called by both firehoses since they share the same configuration and similar code.  But I can't figure out how to distinguish which firehose the event came from.  Is there a way to do this or do I need to create a lambda for each of the firehoses?